# Weird issue with the order of clauses seeming to matter

Tags: mysql

It's not an issue for me I was more just looking for an answer as to WHY it does this.

I have 2 queries both the same with the exception that one has a where clause in a different place (but no so that it should affect the results).

**apologies I deal with sensitive information so these images don't really do this justice**

Query 1:
[image: Query 1]
Query 1 Results:

[image: Query 1 Results]

Query 2:
[image: Query 2]

Query 2 Results:

[image: Query 2 Results]

I guess you will just have to take my word that both queries are exactly the same (aside form the IN statement moving to the top, underneath the date query, in the first query its at the bottom) but there is no subqueries or anything so I don't understand why both queries don't yield the same results lol

**EDIT** : Full queries with changed names;

---

While Re-writing the full query I noticed a hidden OR, god this is embarrassing, the last line is;

```
AND NOT myTable2.field LIKE 'Other Thing' OR 'Some OtherThing'
```

so When I added the line to the bottom it obviously became part of the OR LOL!

Comment: Can you just take the time to MD5()/SHA256()/whatever your fieldnames and any strings? That will make it intelligible but at the same time preserve security! You appear to be saying that your `AND` clauses are identical, it's just the order that's different? Sure, I can understand why the optimizer might pick a different plan depending on the order of the `AND`s, but I'm flummoxed by the idea that the same set of `AND`s gives a different resultset! You're sure it's the same database, same table? Have to ask!

Comment: Can you provide [EXPLAIN EXTENDED](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/06/15/explain-extended-can-tell-you-all-kinds-of-interesting-things/) for both queries?

Comment: You haven't got any sneaky "OR" clauses hiding in there anywhere somewhere, maybe?

Comment: @Vérace I will update original question in a sec with the query with changed field names, and Jerb no there is not

Comment: @Jerb you were right, **shamefully bows head**

Comment: I would delete the question, but can imagine someone else will have this issue lol

Comment: I've expanded on this with a full answer. Not fishing for reputation points honest - it's just that sneaky OR logic bombs hiding amongst the code is one of those things that comes up often enough, that it's worth taking the extra care over..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just to follow up my correct (yay!) comment answer - in my experience *almost everything* along the lines of "weird issue" involving data selection, involves a rogue, unparenthesised "OR" somewhere in the where clause. It's always the first place I'd look.

Typically you write some code along the lines of:

```
WHERE a
AND b OR c
AND d
```

and then when you *look* at the code your mind kind of fills in the parenthesis where you think it ought to be. Whereas order or precedence rules actually perform it thus:

```
WHERE (a AND b) OR (c AND d)
```

A good trick to use when coding, which I tend to do automatically now, is as soon as you use an "OR" anywhere in your code, then add some parenthesis to make it totally clear.

Even if your where clause is simply:

```
WHERE a OR b
```

Then explicitly change it to

```
WHERE ( a OR b )
```

since, you're future-proofing against someone adding to the code later and accidentally writing something like:

```
WHERE a OR b
AND c
```

Comment: I hope the lesson is learned:  Always put parentheses around `OR`.